# PHP 5.2 - php5-pgsql : Depends: phpapi-20090626

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm running this vagrant box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/tierra/boxes/wordpress-php52

I have an old application which can only run on PHP 5.2 with PostgreSQL. This box uses PHP 5.2 which works correctly, and got me some of the way there. I was then able to install a Postgres server, which is also working.

My problem is when I try to:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

I receive this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php5-pgsql : Depends:
>   phpapi-20090626
>                 Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-7+squeeze19) but 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0 is to be installed E: Broken packages

I found some instructions for pinning my packages in apt to certain versions so they don't automatically upgrade. I looked in /etc/apt/preferences.d/php5 and see there are already many packages pinned on this vagrant box, for PHP 5.2. I added php5-pgsql to the bottom of this file:

```
Package: php5-pgsql
Pin: version 5.2*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

I ran apt-get update after that and tried to install the package again, but got the same error. Here's some more info I get when I run:

```
apt-cache showpkg php5-common
```

I get the following list:

```
Package: php5-common
Versions: 
5.3.3-7+squeeze19 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian_dists_squeeze_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.debian.org_dists_squeeze_updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian_dists_squeeze_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 35fa5e0abdb65960311eaf3dfa99d225

5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: d0c21fef525e6be25407d866c992d2ac


Reverse Depends: 
  php5-mysql,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-xsl,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  libapache2-mod-php5,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-cli,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-mcrypt,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-memcache,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-ssh2,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-curl,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php-pear,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-xdebug,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-gd,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-cgi,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5-imagick,php5-common 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0
  php5,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-xsl,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-xmlrpc,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-tidy,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-sybase,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-sqlite,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-snmp,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-recode,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-pspell,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-pgsql,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-odbc,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-mysql,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-mcrypt,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-ldap,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-intl,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-interbase,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-imap,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-gmp,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-gd,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-enchant,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-dev,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-dbg,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-curl,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-cli,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-cgi,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php-pear,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  libapache2-mod-php5filter,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  libapache2-mod-php5,php5-common 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
  php5-memcached,php5-common
  php5-memcache,php5-common
  php5-imagick,php5-common
  php5-geoip,php5-common
  nagvis,php5-common 5.3.0
Dependencies: 
5.3.3-7+squeeze19 - sed (2 4.1.1-1) libc6 (2 2.4) php5-suhosin (0 (null)) php5-json (0 (null)) php5-mhash (0 (null)) 
5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0 - sed (2 4.1.1-1) libc6 (2 2.7-1) php5-json (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
5.3.3-7+squeeze19 - php5-mhash php5-json 
5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0 - php5-json
```

Some of these are listed as 5.2, but a lot are listed as PHP 5.3. The package in question, php5-pgsql indeed seems to indicated it relies on php5-common 5.3, rather than 5.2. Unfortunately, this project will only run on 5.2, so upgrading to 5.3 is NOT an acceptable solution. Instead, I need a way to install php5-pgsql or equivalent while continuing to use PHP 5.2

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Have a similar situation with php5.3.

Comment: The hosting company would no longer support this server, and neither the previous developer nor I could get our local machines configured to run this thing. Instead, the client eventually paid for the upgrades to move the site to a modern environment, and things have been smooth since then.